# What does the 'master' option in the attachment view settings stand for?

Tags: views

I am using some attachment views to display the latest one of different content types in one view.

I was using the first (block) view as the parent view and was attaching the others to this view. This, in many cases ok. But now I ran into some styling issues, caused by the overly complicated markup.

So I decided to delete the block view, convert all the views to attachments and  of the view attachments, and attach all of them to 'master'. I was hoping this would give me a homogeneous markup.

But now the block disappeared completely. It is not even visible in the blocks admin page.

So my question is, what does the 'master' in the attachment options stand for?

Comment: The master display is the default one created automatically for every view. It's not a block, so it won't show up in the list. For views, only their block displays show up in that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master display is the default one created automatically for every view. It's not a block, so it won't show up in the list. For views, only their block displays show up in that list.

A quick trick to get access to the Master display: edit the view then without selecting any of the displays append "/default' to the URL and hit return.

Answer (score 0):

@Alfred Armstrong has well explained what the 'master' attachment option stands for, which I understand directly answers your questions. However, for the problem you have outlined, as a temporary solution, to get it to display the Master, go to admin>structure>views>settings, and click "Always show the master display".

Then simply create a new block view, copy the newly displayed info from the Master to this, and go back to admin>structure>views>settings and turn off "Always show the master display" again.

[Useful link](https://drupal.org/node/1099688)

Comment: Still not clear for what purpose master view is there.any one can more explain it means what is use of master view and how is it related with page,block.

Comment: It is just a default display until you create a new one, like a placeholder.